# Firestore Cloud Function update / transaction slow

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to listen to updates to any bet document, if so, the amount added has to be removed from the users balance. The following code is doing that. The problem is that this can take up to **2 Seconds** with a normal **get** and **update** operation, or like **7 - 10 seconds** with a **transaction**.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import {BetType} from './models/enums';
import {Bet} from './models/Bet';
type DocumentSnapshot = admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;

// const db = admin.firestore();
export const removeMoney = functions.firestore
  .document('bets/{userId}')
  .onWrite(async (change: functions.Change<DocumentSnapshot>, context) => {
    const beforeSnapshot = change.before;
    const afterSnapshot = change.after;
    if(afterSnapshot && beforeSnapshot) {
      const before: Bet = beforeSnapshot.data() as Bet;
      const after: Bet = afterSnapshot.data() as Bet;
      if (after && before) {
        if (before.redAmount !== after.redAmount) {
          await transform(before, after, BetType.red);
        } else if (before.blackAmount !== after.blackAmount) {
          await transform(before, after, BetType.black);
        } else if (before.greenAmount !== after.greenAmount) {
          await transform(before, after, BetType.green);
        }
        return "done";
      }
    }
    return "It was a delete, no action taken";
  });


async function transform(before, after, type: BetType = BetType.black) {
  if(before && after) {
    const amountBefore = before[type] ? before[type] : 0;
    const diff = after[type] - amountBefore;

    const user = (await after.user.get()).data();
    await after.user.update({amount: user.amount - diff})

    /*
    db.runTransaction(transaction => transaction.get(after.user as DocumentReference)
      .then(userDoc => {
        const exists = userDoc.exists;
        if (!exists) { return; }
        const userData = userDoc.data();
        if(!userData) { return; }
        transaction.update(userDoc.ref, {amount: userData.amount - diff});
      }))
      .catch(console.error);
      */
  }


}
```

I just couldn't figure out why it is so slow, any ideas?

Comment: How are you benchmarking these times?  Without a sensible and repeatable benchmark, I am skeptical of any reported times.

Comment: @DougStevenson I stopped the time till the change was seen in the firestore console (the user amount changes)